# Using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

i have the following problem.
I want to escape all special characters in a python string.

```
str='eFEx-x?k=;-'

re.sub("([^a-zA-Z0-9])",r'\\1', str)

'eFEx\\1x\\1k\\1\\1\\1'

str='eFEx-x?k=;-'

re.sub("([^a-zA-Z0-9])",r'\1', str)

'eFEx-x?k=;-'

re.sub("([^a-zA-Z0-9])",r'\\\1', str)
```

I can't seem to win here. '\1' indicates the special character and i want to add a '\' before this special character. but using \1 removes its special meaning and \\1 also does not help.

Comment: Why did the last version not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `r'\\\1'`. That's a backslash (escaped, so denoted `\\`) followed by `\1`.

To verify that this works, try:

```
str = 'eFEx-x?k=;-'
print re.sub("([^a-zA-Z0-9])",r'\\\1', str)
```

This prints:

```
eFEx\-x\?k\=\;\-
```

which I think is what you want. Don't be confused when the interpreter outputs `'eFEx\\-x\\?k\\=\\;\\-'`; the double backslashes are there because the interpreter quotes it output, unless you use `print`.

Comment: >>> re.sub("([^a-zA-Z0-9])",r'\\\1', str)

'eFEx\\-x\\?k\\=\\;\\-'

>>> str='eFEx-x?k=;-'

>>> print re.sub("([^a-zA-Z0-9])",r'\\\1', str)

eFEx\-x\?k\=\;\-

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use `re.escape()`?

```
str = 'eFEx-x?k=;-'
re.escape(str)

'eFEx\\-x\\?k\\=\\;\\-'
```

Comment: This is certainly what you'd want if “special characters” means “characters that have special meaning to regex”. `str.encode('string-escape')` might be another possibility, if it's “characters that are special to Python string literals”. Who knows what's “special”?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding another backslash:

```
s = 'eFEx-x?k=;-'
print re.sub("([^a-zA-Z0-9])",r'\\\1', s)
```